# Integrate Auth0 in an ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, auth0

I try to integrate a basic user authentication in an ASP.NET Core MVC application following the tutorial from https://auth0.com/blog/add-authentication-aspnet-core-mvc/

When I try to login it fails here:

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
```

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from:
> 'https://dev-blah-blah-blah.us.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
> Will retry at '3/14/2024 11:49:04 PM +00:00'.
>
> Exception: System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: [PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]

Very interesting... I get this error on my work laptop but everything runs fine on my personal computer

Comment: Did you use vpn in your work laptop?

Comment: Yes @jason pan, I use VPN

Comment: Could you disconnect vpn, then try again?

Comment: I disconnected, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you kindly check if there is any Network & internet Proxy in your work machine ?

Comment: In addition, you also need to make sure that the time is synchronized, because if the time of the working machine is incorrect, there will be problems with SSL verification, and IDX20803 errors will often be encountered.